# Mount Google Drive as FTP, Web-Share, or with free third-party applications

Tags: google-drive

I would like a free solution to mount my Google Drive with FTP, Web Share, or with third party apps. And I mean something that doesn't sync locally, but directly fetches the data from the cloud. I have tried many apps, but all of them have a price tag.

If you don't get it, I want something like the Drive File Stream ([Website](https://gsuite.google.com/campaigns/index__drive-fs-eap.html)), but for personal needs.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://www.andresoviedo.org/google-drive-ftp-adapter/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on Chromebook by default - you can also do this in Debian.

http://xmodulo.com/mount-google-drive-linux.html

Cool tool by SpiderPig though!